# PayPal API: How i get sale id from a payment made in PayPal?

Tags: java, paypal

Hi, I don't know how to get the sale_id of a PayPal transaction so that I can later use that code in a refund in Java.

The payment response, returns only the id (which is not the sale_id or transaction id), intent = "sale", the cart id and some dates. I understand that the id that starts with PAYID is what I'm going to find the sale_id with. I have searched the PayPal API to see if there was something about it, but I have not found anything for Java that returns that id.

Therefore my question is the following: **Do you know any way to obtain the sale id or transaction id of a payment in Java?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PAYIDs and sale_ids are returned by the v1/payments API, which is deprecated. You should upgrade to v2/checkout/orders instead.

When executing a PAYID, the sale_id will be in the response. Look through the entire response object, perhaps in `transactions` or `related_resources`, you will find it. Don't have an example offhand since this is a deprecated API.

---

As for how to upgrade to a current integration:

Follow the [Set up standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) guide and make 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). Both routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller.

Pair those 2 routes with the frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server